# Dart js-interop with jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, dart

I'm new to Dart and I'm having trouble getting started with the js-interop library. I want to add a slider from jquery ui to my page, but I cannot figure out how to do the slider() setup call from Dart. Is js-interop the correct way of doing this? Some help with this would be much appreciated.

```
void main() {
  js.scoped(() {
    var slider = query('#slider-range');
    var options = js.map({
      'range': true,
      'values': [ 17, 67 ]
    });
    // This doesn't work. Element has no method named slider.
    slider.slider(options);

    // In javascript it's done like this:
    // $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    //   range: true,
    //   values: [ 17, 67 ]
    // });

    // This alert works.
    js.context.alert('Hello from Dart via JS');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you have to use *js.context.$('#slider-range')* instead of *query('#slider-range')*. Basically, *js.context* allows to access any Javascript variable. By using *js.context.$* you get access to the *jQuery* javascript object (ie. *$*) on dart side.

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

void main() {
  js.scoped(() {
    var slider = js.context.$('#slider-range');
    var options = js.map({
      'range': true,
      'values': [ 17, 67 ]
    });
    slider.slider(options);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your solution seems good. But now I get an error on the var options line: http://paste2.org/p/2419107 Any ideas?

Comment: As of r14094 Map.getKeys() has been changed to Map.keys. Last version of js-interop in pub.dartlang.org does not contain the update with that change. Until a new version is landing, you have to use directly git://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop.git that contains the patch.

Comment: FYI js-0.0.9 has been published on pub.dartlang.org. See http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js

Comment: what happens if the element to be selected is part of a component in shadow dom?

Comment: Whatever you use (jQuery, querySelector...) you cannot query an element inside a shadowRoot if the based element (`window` by default) is not inside the same shadowRoot.

Answer (score 1):

Another sample code:

```
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

js.context.jQuery();
var context = js.context;  
var param = js.map({ 'modal': true, "width":1000, "height":600});
js.context.jQuery("#dialog").dialog(param);
```

in html

```
<script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
```

The above code open a div as dialog using jQuery.

Comment: This comment is not valid anymore. Can anyone update it?